# Jasmine and node.js

Tags: javascript, testing, node.js, jasmine

Have some `Jasmine+Rhino` combo to test the javascript code and trying to shift to `node.js`. However, couldn't find any setup instructions on the net (but only [this](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) link, with nearly zero instructions). Any help on how to make it true (on Ubuntu) will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I thought the same thing (regarding documentation) when I first tried to use jasmine-node. As it turns out, though, there's virtually nothing to set up--it works just like RSpec or other testing tools you might be used to. To use Jasmine with your Node project, do the following:

1. Make sure `jasmine-node` is installed and that you can run its executable.
2. Write your specs! I have a sample spec below these steps.
3. Run your specs with the command `jasmine-node specs/` (where `specs/` points to the directory with your specs).

That's it! You may find it beneficial to use some sort of build tool, like `cake` for CoffeeScript or [`jake`](https://github.com/mde/jake).

Here's a quick example of part of a spec from a small project I used jasmine-node on recently; apologies that it's in CoffeeScript.  (As an aside: to run jasmine-node against CoffeeScript specs, pass it the `--coffee` option.)

```
Chess   = require('../lib/chess')
Board   = Chess.Board
jasmine = require('jasmine-node')

describe "A chess board", ->
  beforeEach ->
    @board = new Board

  it "should convert a letter/number position into an array index", ->
    expect(Board.squares["a1"]).toEqual(0)
    expect(Board.squares["b1"]).toEqual(1)
    expect(Board.squares["a2"]).toEqual(16)
    expect(Board.squares["h8"]).toEqual(119)

  it "should know if an array index represents a valid square", ->
    expect(Board.is_valid_square 0).toBeTruthy()
    expect(Board.is_valid_square 7).toBeTruthy()
    expect(Board.is_valid_square 8).toBeFalsy()
    expect(Board.is_valid_square 15).toBeFalsy()
    expect(Board.is_valid_square 119).toBeTruthy()
    expect(Board.is_valid_square 120).toBeFalsy()
    expect(Board.is_valid_square 129).toBeFalsy()
    expect(Board.is_valid_square -1).toBeFalsy()

  it "should start off clear", ->
    for i in [0..127]
      if Board.is_valid_square(i)
        expect(@board.piece_on(i)).toBeNull()

  describe "#place_piece", ->
    it "should place a piece on the board", ->
      piece = jasmine.createSpy("piece")
      @board.place_piece "a1", piece
      expect(@board.piece_on "a1").toEqual(piece)

    it "should set the piece's location to the given square's index", ->
      piece = jasmine.createSpyObj(Piece, ["position"])
      @board.place_piece "b5", piece
      expect(piece.position).toEqual(65)
```

[Edit]

You can also add a `spec_helper` file (with the appropriate extension for your project) at the root of your `specs/` directory. Here's the contents of mine, which adds a new matcher to Jasmine:

```
jasmine = require('jasmine-node')

beforeEach ->
 this.addMatchers
   toInclude: (should_include) ->
     for value in @actual
       return true if value == should_include
     false
```

Comment: charming! just another clarification please: if my javascript code is supposed to run in the browser (DOM model etc), then do I need any additions to jasmine-node (say `Zombie.js`: http://zombie.labnotes.org/)?

Comment: @BreakPhreak It depends on what your testing. If your testing code **dependent** on the DOM then you will need to include a DOM library for node (like Zombie.js). However, most project use the DOM but are not focused on the DOM. In this case you can modularize your code so that you have the DOM manipulations separate from the functions you want to test and only test the non DOM features in the jasmine spec. It is also appropriate to use jasmine spies to stub/mock the DOM specific functions so that no DOM support is needed when running via jasmine-node (could be considered best practise)

Comment: @Sukima: thanks! my code actually uses the DOM very intensively (and must have it cleanly under the fingerprints)

Comment: @BreakPhreak There are dom testing libraries out there. In your case adding a DOM library to your node tests would be appropriate. If you like jQuery you might find [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) useful.

Comment: @BreakPhreak There are dom testing libraries out there. In your case adding a DOM library to your node tests would be appropriate. If you like jQuery you might find [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) useful.